# I can't seem to get the XPATH right for XSD UNIQUE Constraint

Tags: xml, unique-constraint

I've been trying to get the `UNIQUE` constraint placed on some attributes I have in a fairly basic XSD Schema. I'm using XMLSpy and i'm wanting to put a unique constraint around TEMPLATE.ID for my nodes (i.e. it's important that they remain unique).

I've put the below in place and tried the following:

### Secenario 1

```
<xs:unique name="uniqueviewid">
  <xs:selector xpath="./views"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
</xs:unique>
```

**Result:**
XSD: Validates Ok. XML Validates but doesn't uphold the unique constraint (ie two or more elements with the same id aren't picked up

### Scenario 2

```
<xs:unique name="uniqueviewid">
  <xs:selector xpath="views"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
</xs:unique>
```

**Results* Same as Scenario 1. XSD Validates, XML Validates but ignores duplicate `@id` in view element

### Scenario 3

```
<xs:unique name="uniqueviewid">
  <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
</xs:unique>
```

Results: XSD Validates and XML Validats and it respects the UNIQUE constrint (ie if duplicate views with `@id` it throws an invaldation as per design).

Problem is that the wild card is "*" which means all subnodes under VIEWPODS will be validated, which isnot what I want. I instead want the contraint to be focused on VIEWPOS/VIEWS/@ID exact path.

I think my XPATH is all wrong but i can't think of what i'm doing specifically wrong?

---

### The example XML.

This is the example XML.

```
<config xmlns="http://tempuri.org/RIAGenicConfig.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/RIAGenicConfig.xsd RIAGenicConfig.xsd">
  <view>
    <viewpods>
      <views id="view1"/>
      <views id="view1"/>
    </viewpods>
  </view>
</config>
```

### The XSD in Question.

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://tempuri.org/RIAGenicConfig.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/RIAGenicConfig.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/RIAGenicConfig.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" id="RIAGenicConfig">
  <xs:element name="config">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="view">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
              <xs:element name="viewpods">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element name="views" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="id"/>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="blah"/>
                  </xs:choice>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:unique name="uniqueviewid">
                  <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
                  <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
                </xs:unique>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qualify the xpath selection for ***mstns:views*** instead of *(all elements):

```
<xs:unique name="uniqueviewid">
  <xs:selector xpath="mstns:views"/>
   <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
</xs:unique>
```

Comment: Where did the mstns come from?

Comment: From the XSD.  It contains the namespace definition: xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/RIAGenicConfig.xsd"

Comment: Thanks.  My xml schema had set xmlns to be the same as my target xml, which I thought would be enough.  I added a sub-namespace (is that what you'd call it?) to the schema and used that for my xpaths and now everything works. \o/